# Output for last loop is not what is expected

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to multiply two matrices, but get different output for the last column of the output matrix. There must be some logic error but can't spot it.

I still don't know how to debug, so that's why.

```
    if(aCollumn == bRow) {
            for(i = 0; i < aCollumn; i++){
                    for(j = 0; j < bRow; j++) {
                            for(n = 0; n < aCollumn; n++){
                                    product = matrixA[i][n] * matrixB[n][j];
                                    sum += product;
                            }
                            matrixAB[i][j] = sum;
                            sum = 0;
                    }
            }
    }
    else {
            printf("Matrices are not compatible for multiplication. \n");
    }
```

Comment: As a matter of principle coding: Always set a variable to zero _before_ the loop where it is used; not after. Here `sum=0;` before `for(n=0..`

Comment: Also show the declaration or `sum`, so it is verifiable that it is indeed intitialized to `0`.

Comment: Here is my declaration.         int aRow, aCollumn, bRow, bCollumn, i, j, n, sum = 0, product = 0;

Comment: In `matrixA[i][n] * matrixB[n][j]`, what do you consider the column and what the row? If you get these wrong, you are mutiplying out of bounds.

Comment: in matrixA[i][n] i is the row because I am multiplying every element in that row. for matrix[n][j], j is the column for i am multiplying elements in its columns to the row elements of Matrix A.

Comment: Got it! I should be comparing "i < aRow" instead of 'aCollumn' and 'j < bCollumn' and 'j < bRow for the dimensions of my matrixAB. I've been comparing it wrong thats why i get out of bounds results.

Answer (score 1):

when you multiply long integer by long integer (signed 32 bit+31 bits of data) result could be up to signed 63 bit (31+31=62 + 1 bit for sign) and when you accumulate it range gets even larger, with log2 bits of number of accumulation operations. your code don't tell if matrixA and matrixB are long or short integer, but even for short integers accumulation may cause overflow. you could protect your code with saturation or having low enough values, but it requires more information. please refer to [1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/39db/b9abfe3521981c394e8e4bbd9a45832218a0.pdf) in case this is your case